# Question about notation of symmetry permutations in tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, permutations, tensor-products, tensors

In Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, John Lee writes:

$$
{ }^\sigma \alpha\left(v_1, \ldots, v_k\right)=\alpha\left(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)}\right)
$$
Note that ${ }^\tau\left({ }^\sigma \alpha\right)={ }^{\tau \sigma} \alpha$, where $\tau \sigma$ represents the composition of $\tau$ and $\sigma$, that is, $\tau \sigma(i)=\tau(\sigma(i))$. (This is the reason for putting $\sigma$ before $\alpha$ in the notation $\alpha$, instead of after it.)

Later on, he writes:
If $\tau \in S_k$ is any permutation, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
(\operatorname{Sym} \alpha)\left(v_{\tau(1)}, \ldots, v_{\tau(k)}\right)
& =\frac{1}{k !} \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} {}^{\sigma}\alpha\left(v_{\tau(1)}, \ldots, v_{\tau(k)}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{k !} \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} {}^{\tau \sigma} \alpha\left(v_1, \ldots, v_k\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

**Question: Why is it $\tau\sigma$ and not $\sigma\tau$? $\tau$ is being applied first and so it must stand second, right?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you noted: $^{\tau \sigma} \alpha = ^\tau (^\sigma \alpha)$, and $^\tau (^\sigma \alpha) (v_1,\dots,v_n) = (^\sigma \alpha) (v_{\tau(1)},\dots,v_{\tau(n)})$. So it's all correct, isn't it? :) Here specifically it would not really matter of course, since both $\sigma \tau$ and $\tau \sigma$ go through all possible permutations, but the way it's written is correct.

If you're uneasy about this still, it might be healthy to first try and write down the proof for the identity $^{\tau \sigma} \alpha = ^\tau (^\sigma \alpha)$, because the order of permuting indices definitely also trips me up at times (I don't know if Lee does this in detail in his book). Let us define $w_i := v_{\tau(i)}$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Then

$$ \begin{align} (^\tau (^\sigma \alpha))(v_1,\dots,v_n) 
&= (^\sigma \alpha) (v_{\tau(1)},\dots,v_{\tau(n)}) \\
&= (^\sigma \alpha) (w_1,\dots,w_n)  \\
&= \alpha (w_{\sigma(1)},\dots,w_{\sigma(n)}) \\
&= \alpha (v_{\tau(\sigma(1))},\dots,w_{\tau(\sigma(n))}) \\
&= (^{\tau \sigma} \alpha) (v_1,\dots,v_n).
\end{align} $$

Note that redefining the $v_{\tau(i)} =: w_i$ was necessary to put the indices in the argument of $^\sigma\alpha$ back into the correct order $1,2,...,n$, which we need to apply the definition of $^\sigma \alpha$.  Had we applied $\sigma$ directly onto the indices $\tau(1),\dots,\tau(n)$, we would have ended up with a different result, $\sigma(\tau(1)), \dots, \sigma(\tau(n))$. This may be what you would have expected?